# Spree customize menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I need to customize the Spree (v1.1.1) menu since actually it only has the "Home" link.

I tried by creating an override as

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/shared/_main_nav_bar",
                 :name => "home-link",
                 :remove => "#home-link")
```

Here I was just trying to remove "Home" to see if it'd work.
And I also tried by creating a view `/app/views/spree/shared/_main_nav_bar.html.erb` but nothing, I can't get it working.

How can I do?
Then, why sometimes it works overriding templates while sometime I do need overrides to alter the base layout? I've read the guide but I couldn't find any explanation about this. Shouldn't it just work with my overrides/custom views?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had simmilar problems as you. As a result, I've created the gem to manage menu bars in spree: [spree_essential_menus](http://blog.brzezinka.eu/projects/spree-essential-menus-menu-management-plugin-for-spree-ecommerce?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=spree-essential-menus-menu-management-plugin-for-spree-ecommerce).

I think it may help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are matching a file that doesn't exist.  The file you are looking for is at https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/1-1-stable/core/app/views/spree/shared/_store_menu.html.erb

So you want your code to look like this:

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/shared/_store_menu",
             :name => "home-link",
             :remove => "#home-link")
```

When you are looking through the spree views on github make sure you are looking at the branch for the version you are using.  "_main_bar_nav.html.erb" doens't exist on the 1.1.stable branch but does on master.

As far as when to use which, that a matter of how much you want to change.  If you are making small tweaks i would use deface.  If you are overhauling the whole view system (often recommended on big builds) then you want to replace the views.